# Python True/False if/elif/else condition

Tags: python

Aim :To check if the string is alphanumric , numeric or has just alphabets

Code :

```
s2 = "123test"
if s2.isalnum():
print "String is alphanumeric"
elif s2.isalpha():
print "String is alpha"
elif s2.isdigit():
print "String is numeric"
else:
print "No Idea what the string is"
```

Error:

```
 print "String is alphanumeric"
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

When I do `print s2.isalnum()` by itself it prints `True` . I am not sure what is wrong with my above piece of code.

Version : 2.6

Comment: Is your indentation the same as above?

Comment: yes my indentation in the code is same as above .

Comment: Indentation looks wrong.  You need consistent indentation for python to work.

Comment: Even if the indentation is wrong, OP wouldn't get a `SyntaxError`, right? He'd get an `IndentationError`.

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code wrong, or the error message? Because the error message you pasted is referring to a line of code that doesn't match anything in the code you pasted.

Comment: Or… is it possible that you added the colon in your text editor, didn't save, and tried to run the script again?

Comment: As a side note: If `isalnum` is false, `isalpha` and `isdigit` are guaranteed to also be false, so most of this code isn't going to do anything useful. You want to check `isalbum` _last_, not _first_.

Comment: Now that you've been introduced to the fact that indentation is required in python, make sure you only use spaces for indentation(preferably 4 spaces) because mixing spaced and tabs can also raise `IndentationError`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python, indentation is important

```
s2 = "123test"
if s2.isalnum():
    print "String is alphanumeric"
elif s2.isalpha():
    print "String is alpha"
elif s2.isdigit():
    print "String is numeric"
else:
    print "No Idea what the string is"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you properly copied and pasted your error message:

```
if s2.isalnum()
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

… then the problem is that you forgot the colon at the end of the `if` line.

So, change it to:

```
if s2.alnum():
```

… and it will be fine.

---

Well, it will be fine in that you'll get past the `SyntaxError` and run an `IndentationError`. But jh314's answer already tells you how to solve that.

Comment: He does have the colon there.

Comment: @2rs2ts: Not according to the error message. So, either he's pasted the error message wrong, or he's pasted the code wrong, or he's edited the code but forgotten to save it so he's running the old version, or… And it almost has to be the first or third one, not the second, because there is no `SyntaxError` on the line as posted.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for the answer. My apologies. I posted the wrong error message. I had already got past that error message by adding the colon mark to the end of the if statement.

Comment: @misguided: It's important to always copy and paste exactly the code you used and exactly the error you got (preserving indentation), or it makes it very hard to help you.

Comment: @abarnert will keep that in mind mate.Apologies for the inconvinience :)